# Is there a bag of tricks for fully-connected networks training on tabular data?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, references

There are lots of discussions and research about tips and tricks that are helpful for convolutional networks training. (Like in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.01187)). The new architectures/optimizers/layers emerge very often, especially in the fields of computer vision and NLP. I wonder is there something similar for the fully connected networks applied to the tabular/structured data classification?

The most widely used approach I see is to use embeddings layers, concatenate them with numerical input, and pass it through the stack of fully-connected layers (probably with dropouts and batch normalization). 
Are there any other recommendations or state-of-the-art methods applied for the tabular data, any custom architectures suitable for this task? Or the "simple" approach outlined above is the best available solution?

I understand that people mostly use boosted trees or linear models in this case but I would like to investigate possible solutions available in the Deep Learning world.

Comment: While the focus is on debugging networks, there are a number of tricks suggested here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352036/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-learn/352037#352037

Comment: Very thorough and elaborated post! Thank you. I'll definitely go through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are lots of them.  I haven't read the [second edition](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-35289-8) (published 2012), but the first is very good.

[image]

Somewhat old now, but the [Comp.ai.neural-nets FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part1/preamble.html) list also has plenty of good advice that is still valid today.

Comment: Great, thank you! Actually, some time ago I've already encountered the reference to this book somewhere but didn't pay proper attention to it :)